# What is the use of designDialogPath?

Tags: aem

I am seeing from wcmcore [page component](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/page/v1/page/.content.xml),

```
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="Page (v1)"
    sling:resourceSuperType="wcm/foundation/components/basicpage/v1/basicpage"
    componentGroup=".core-wcm"
    designDialogPath="core/wcm/components/page/v1/page/cq:design_dialog"/>
```

What is the purpose of designDialogPath? My dialog from page policy works even without this property. I couldnt realize the difference adding and not adding this property. 
Can you please point the purpose of this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What designDialogPath path does?

In the context of `wcm core component`, `designDialogPath` enables you to access `Page Design` mode from the template in `/conf` folder. Screenshot below.

[image: With Page Design]

When you remove this node, you will not be able to access `Page Design` from the template. That option does not show up. Screenshot below.

[image: Dialog Node]
[image: Without design mode]

---

#### Why include designDialogPath?

It's primary use is to define clientlibs that should be loaded for pages using this template. Adobe has added an `helpPath` in that component to explain this. Link [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/core-components/using/page-v1.html#DesignDialog).

There are use cases where the same page needs to be rendered differently in terms of styling and as a developer, you can define different clientlibs for different layouts and leave it to the author to inject the required clientlibs based on the use case.

I feel this is just another step by Adobe to give more control to content authors.